# MVC C# Powershell not remembering previous commands across methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, powershell

Something I'm doing wrong (obviously) - would love some insight into where I'm going wrong. (Pretty new to C# and MVC so apologies....etc.)

Secnario: Creating a Powershell runspace within ASP.Net MVC 5 and running different Powershell commands across controller methods.

Problem: Even though Powershell and Runspace variables are declared in the class and commands are added to the class Powershell instance via each method, it doesn't remember the previous commands....

Example (Code below) Runspace and powershell instances are created in Initialise() method. The LoadModules() method correctly loads the VMware snapin module. Finally, the Connect method fails, as it can't see any of the CMDlets that *should* have been loaded in the LoadModules() method.

VIEW

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}




<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Initialise", "Home")',
                datatype: "html",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#msgBox').append(response);
                }
            });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("Connect", "Home")',
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (response) {
                $('#msgBox').append("<br />");
                $('#msgBox').append(response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#clickMe").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("PowerOff", "Home")',
                datatype: "html",
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#msgBox').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="msgBox" style="width:400px; height:400px; background-color:#eaeaea; border:#000 1px solid"></div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //Initialise Powsershell runspace and instantiate
    Runspace rSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    PowerShell psInstance = PowerShell.Create();



    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Initialise()
    {
        //Open runspace and attach to Powershell instance
        rSpace.Open();
        psInstance.Runspace = rSpace;
        return Json("Powershell bubble created");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadModules()
    {
        //Load VMware module
        psInstance.AddScript("Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core");

        try
        {
            var result = psInstance.Invoke();
        }
        catch (CmdletInvocationException e)
        {
            psInstance.Commands.Clear();
            rSpace.Close();
            return Json("Oh noes: " + e.ToString());
        }

        psInstance.Commands.Clear();
        return Json("Vmware Modules Loaded");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Connect()
    {

        //Connect to VI-server
        psInstance.AddCommand("Connect-VIServer");
        psInstance.AddParameter("-Server", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
        psInstance.AddParameter("-username", @"xxxxxxxxx");
        psInstance.AddParameter("-password", @"xxxxxxxx");

        try
        {
            var result = psInstance.Invoke();
        }
        catch (CmdletInvocationException e)
        {
            psInstance.Commands.Clear();
            rSpace.Close();
            throw e;
        }

        psInstance.Commands.Clear();
        return Json("Connected to vfarm-03");
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with MVC, but are you sure that all requests share same `HomeController` instance, and not new instance created for each request?

Answer (score 1):

As the comments are saying, controllers are instantiated per request. That's why this doesn't work. When for example the `Initialise`action is called it will open the runspace, but all of this is lost as the controller instance will be destroyed and a new one will be created the next request.

You either need to create a static instance which is shared between all requests, or you need to instantiate PowerShell on each request.

Comment: Thank you sir! Worked a charm. Should have thought of that, but my brain was fried last night :)

Comment: Great! What solution did you go for? Did you create a static instace or initialise a new one in each request?

Comment: Just created a static instance :) Nice and simple!

Comment: Great! If the answer was helpful, I suggest you mark the question as solved. :-)